# Replace values in column with column values from other dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one with more columns (but two of them are important) and the second with two columns. 
df1:

```
col_a  col_b
101     104
102     201
103     301
505     601
```

df2:

```
col_a_a col_b_b
420      637
425      643
201      701
601      702
```

I need the next thing. Lookup at `df1['col_b']` and if exist in `df2['col_a_a']` then replace it with `df2['col_b_b']`.

I have tried two ways:

```
df1['col_b'] = np.where(df1['col_b'] == df2['col_a_a'], df2['col_b_b'], df1['col_b'])

df1.col_b[df1.col_b == df2.col_a_a] = df2.col_b_b
```

But both of them return me the same error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Desired output:

```
col_a  col_b
    101     104
    102     701
    103     301
    505     702
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1['col_b'] = df1['col_b'].replace(df2.set_index('col_a_a')['col_b_b'])
print (df1)
   col_a  col_b
0    101    104
1    102    701
2    103    301
3    505    702
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `pd.Series.map`:

```
df1['col_b'] = df1['col_b'].map(df2.set_index('col_a_a')['col_b_b']).fillna(df1['col_b'])
```

Depending on your data, this may be more efficient.